# Newcomer to AWS question about Roles/Groups logic

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I understand this is a really open question but I wondered what approaches you would all take.

Backstory:
Making a website that will have many different Roles that should have different access levels to the site.
Imagine a Role of Admin, Mod, Team Leader and Member. But there are say 3 teams with each of these roles within them. The Roles should only have permission level access to their own Team. all can access their own accounts and each others but only certain levels can change details as you go up. Admin is top level with full access, Mod can access say blogs and wikis, Team leader can manage the Team's details ect

What tools would you use to achieve this?

We are currently using AWS Amplify, Cognito and potentially AppSync.

Could i achieve this efficiently with IAM Groups or IAM Roles or AppSync?
Im new to all of this.

My initial thought was to grab the Cognito Group, Role and Tag Details when they login and store their TeamID and Tag/PositionID upon initial login and then do checks on the pages to compare the stores group and access levels and change the UI accordingly but is that the best way? Is there better free tools out there?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: IAM is used to manage access to AWS resources, like EC2 instances, security groups, load balancers, S3 buckets, or RDS instances. Are you trying to manage access to those types of resources, or something else inside yoru application?

Comment: I'm, very new to this so im really just asking for a steer i guess, like a go look at this for that. The way I sort of envision it would be pulling down a team from a database table in a page and Team members would only see other team members. The Team leaders the same + look at the attendance and hours worked. Mods all of above +  can say remove members and add new team leaders and the Admins can do everthing + remove or add mods. Im using Coginito for my userpools so i wondered how it all connects up

Comment: So basically ill make an Admin user. He can create a Team and assign members to their roles within that team and then I'll somehow dictate the roles and permission levels

Comment: Ive done some digging and the possible plan (correct if im wrong) could be to use AppSync to limit access depending on level and store it all in a DynamoDB table? would that make sense

Answer (score 0):

Roles / groups are confusing.

Best explanation is you give roles to AWS services most of the time, and you assign real humans to a group.

If there is a dev or leader that has access to multiple different AWS projects, you can give them a role as well.

A majority of the time, roles are saved for Amazon services, like EC2 instances that need to access AWS services.

The majority of the time you put humans in groups. Unless the dev has an IAM account that is not under you. For example, if you are name@projectOne and projectOne is the root account, and someone else is name2@projectThree which is in a different part of your company. You could give them a role because their IAM account they are logging into is from a different root account.

Majority of the time, save roles for AWS instances like Ec2, etc. Just put IAM users in groups. If they are not under your root account, give them a role and then once they are in, they can get put in groups too, or can assign themselves into a group.

Don't give lower dev's roles, unless they are coming from a different dev team. If it is the same dev team (under the same root) just assign them to groups.

Continually check what permissions are being used by the devs in your group. Click on their name and then click on security advisor. If you see they aren't using a bunch of things (because it will show last day used...) then modify the group they are in, or create a new group for those specific activities and put them in that. AWS recommends giving the least access necessary.

Comment: Thank you for all the info!. In terms of limiting access to the DB, would you use Appsync groups to limit access to certain areas in  a DynamoTable?